# Problem with copying my file into the directories

Tags: java, directory, java-io

I have a problem with copying my file into the directories.

This is the code i have written

```
package icecream1;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class Icecream1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            TextIO.readFile("icecream.txt"); // open file
            System.out.println("Please make sure the file is present before");

            System.out.println("running the program.");

            System.exit(1); // Terminates the program.

        }

        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            System.out.println("Can't open file \"icecream.txt\" for reading!");

        }

        int numberCones = 1; // stores total number of cones

        int numberStrawberry = 1; // stores total number of strawberry cones

        double percent;

        while (TextIO.eof()) { // read one line

            String data; // stores icecream flavor

            data = TextIO.getln(); // read a line

            numberCones += 1; // increment count

            if (data.equals("Strawberry"))

                numberStrawberry += 1;

        } // while

//calculate percent of strawberry icecream

        percent = 100.0 * numberStrawberry / numberCones;

//display result    
        String ourDirectory = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();

        TextIO.readFile(ourDirectory + "//dist//icecream.txt");

        System.out.println(TextIO.getlnString());

        System.out.println("The total Number of cones: " + numberCones);

        System.out.println("The total Number of Strawberry cones: " + numberStrawberry);

        System.out.println("The total Percentage of Strawberry cones: " + percent + " %");
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

---

```
package icecream1;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class Icecream1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            TextIO.readFile("icecream.txt"); // open file
            System.out.println("Please make sure the file is present before");

            System.out.println("running the program.");

            System.exit(1); // Terminates the program.

        }

        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            System.out.println("Can't open file \"icecream.txt\" for reading!");

        }

        int numberCones = 1; // stores total number of cones

        int numberStrawberry = 1; // stores total number of strawberry cones

        double percent;

        while (TextIO.eof()) { // read one line

            String data; // stores icecream flavor

            data = TextIO.getln(); // read a line

            numberCones += 1; // increment count

            if (data.equals("Strawberry"))

                numberStrawberry += 1;

        } // while

        //calculate percent of strawberry icecream

        percent = 100.0 * numberStrawberry / numberCones;

        //display result    
        String ourDirectory = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();

        TextIO.readFile(ourDirectory + "//dist//icecream.txt");

        System.out.println(TextIO.getlnString());
        System.out.println("The total Number of cones: " + numberCones);
        System.out.println("The total Number of Strawberry cones: " + numberStrawberry);
        System.out.println("The total Percentage of Strawberry cones: " + percent + " %");
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

Can't open file "icecream.txt" for reading!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To format your post and make it easier to read, try putting the code between three backticks - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) link for an example. This makes it easier to answer your question.